# Powershell script crashes when starting from shortcut

Tags: powershell

I've got a PowerShell script containing a pop-up window:

```
($Host.UI.PromptForChoice($someParameter))
```

Unfortunately, the process crashes when the pop-up window should appear.

This only happens when I try to call this script from a shortcut: `(C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File PathToFile -windowstyle Hidden)`

Is there any way to bypass this issue?

Comment: Hello, on what architecture are you running? 32Bit/64Bit?
Could you provide us with the ```$PSVersionTable``` information?

Comment: Any space characters in `PathToFile` ?

Comment: What happens if you omit `-WindowStyle Hidden`?

Comment: Show us all of the code up to this point.  A good way to test for and capture the error message you're running into is to launch a command prompt, then run the shortcut text from within the prompt.  Then you'll see the errors which occur.